# The data is still loading. When the data binding is completed, the Grid raises the 'bindingcomplete' event

Tags: angularjs

i have the problem of jqx grid in angularjs at the time of refresh the grid,

***Error* = jqxGrid: The data is still loading. When the data binding is completed, the Grid raises the 'bindingcomplete' event. Call this function in the 'bindingcomplete' event handler**

I used this code: **$rootScope.bloginGridSettings.apply('updatebounddata', 'refresh');**

In normal JS it's working but in angularjs, is not working..

Answer (score 2):

You need to do your code inside the following event.

```
    $("#GRID_NAME").on("bindingcomplete", function (event) {
        //Your Code Here will run after the grid fully loads  
    });
```